# Doctrine ODM Connection URI on ZF2

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I'm using Zend Module DoctrineMongoODMModule and I would like to connect to MongoDB with Connection String

With array settings it working fine :

```
'server'    => 'localhost',
'port'      => '10152',
'user'      => 'test',
'password'  => 'test',
'dbname'    => 'base',
'options'   => array()
```

But when i want connect with URI like this :

```
'connectionString' => 'mongodb://test:test@server1:10152,server2:10152/base'
```

It doesnt work. I got this error :

> The option "connectionString" does not have a matching setConnectionString setter method which must be defined

The reason that i want Uri connection is that I using Replica database and would like to connect both server.

Answer (score 0):

The options usually start with snake_case and are converted into setters/getters. For the connection, the `Connection` [options class is used](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Options/Connection.php#L31). This options class is used by the [connection factory](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Service/ConnectionFactory.php#L41).

First, you could try to set the connetion string with `connection_string`. I haven't tested it, but it should work according to the standards of the Options classes.

Next, you could set the server part with `server1:10152,server2`. If you check the factory, all parts are just concatenated. It will result in a same version of the connection string build.